# SQL Query with multiple columns and an aggregate function using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having troubles with my SQL query. I have the following `movie` table:

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID_MOVIE                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 TITLE                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 GENRE                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 YEAR                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 COUNTRY                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DURATION                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 BUDGET                                             NUMBER(10)
 INCOMES                                            NUMBER(10)
 ID_MOVIE_PREV                                      NUMBER(4)
 ID_DIRECTOR
```

i tried this command: `select m.genre, max(m.budget),m.title from movie m group by m.genre,m.title;` and got this result:

```
GENRE                          MAX(M.BUDGET) TITLE
------------------------------ ------------- ------------------------------
Western                              1200000 The Good, the Bad and the Ugly
Horror                                806947 Psycho
Crime                                7000000 The Godfather: Part III
Action                             185000000 The Dark Knight
Drama                               26000000 Philadelphia
Drama                               13000000 In the Name of the Father
Action                             150000000 Batman Begins
Historical                          23800000 The Last Emperor
Science-fiction                      5800000 Planet of the Apes
Crime                                7000000 The Godfather
Action                             230000000 The Dark Knight Rises

GENRE                          MAX(M.BUDGET) TITLE
------------------------------ ------------- ------------------------------
Comedy                              28000000 Zoolander
Crime                                9000000 Pulp Fiction
Crime                               13000000 The Godfather: Part II
War                                 70000000 Saving Private Ryan
Science-fiction                     28000000 Blader Runner
Drama                               33000000 Gran Torino
```

I'd like to have the title of the maximum of each gender. 
Can anyone tell me on where is my mistake? Thank you by advance!

Comment: Do you mean genre instead of gender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your query does not actually aggregate, since you would expect that `(genre, title)` tuples are unique in the table.

You can use a correlated subquery to filter the table:

```
select genre,title, budget
from movie m
where budget = (
    select max(m1.budget)
    from movie m1
    where m1.genre = m.genre
)
```

This seems to me like the simplest way to phrase what you are trying to achieve. For performance, consider an index on `(genre, budget)`.

Here is a **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e14089df588fbb3e49ce46d4061b6de6)** (based on the above assumption that your current resultset can be considered as your raw data):

```
GENRE           | TITLE                          |    BUDGET
:-------------- | :----------------------------- | --------:
Western         | The Good, the Bad and the Ugly |   1200000
Horror          | Psycho                         |    806947
Historical      | The Last Emperor               |  23800000
Action          | The Dark Knight Rises          | 230000000
Comedy          | Zoolander                      |  28000000
Crime           | The Godfather: Part II         |  13000000
War             | Saving Private Ryan            |  70000000
Science-fiction | Blader Runner                  |  28000000
Drama           | Gran Torino                    |  33000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` analytic function :

```
select genre, budget,title
  from
  (
      select genre, budget, title,
             row_number() over (partition by genre order by budget desc) as rn       
        from movie 
   )
  where rn = 1
```

grouping is performed by partition by and maximum value for budget is found by ordering by descending budget.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=296b29d8d7cb971e6d7dbf29db4b2c92)</kbd>

Comment: What is the use of "q.*" or how is it called this function?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use aggregation:

```
select genre,
       max(title) keep (dense_rank first order by budget desc) as title,
       max(budget) as budget
from movie m
group by genre;
```

The `keep` expression is essentially doing a get-the-first-value function.